# Eclipse can't read code format of RenderScript .rs file

Tags: android, c, eclipse, c99, renderscript

I have a very good Java knowledge for Android (1 year of development), and now I'm trying to learn the Android RenderScript API (but there isn't much documentations for it) anyway, I'm having some problems with it.

I learned that we need to add the following lines on `project.propert`:

```
renderscript.target=19
renderscript.support.mode=true
```

I created a .rs file in `com.mypackage.script` called `FireworkScript`, which has the following:

```
#pragma version(1)

#pragma rs java_package_name(com.mypackage.script)

#include "rs_graphics.rsh"

int root(){

    return 0;

}

void init(){

}
```

Innitially I had some problems with the RenderScript v8 support library, but I fixed it by manually adding the **renderscript-v8.jar** to my project (**Build Path >> Configure Build Path >> Libraries >> Add External JARs**)

As expected, Eclipse generated the `ScriptC_FireworkScript.java` at **gen** folder and the `fireworkscript.bc` at **bin/res/bc/raw**

**But the problem is**: Eclipse doesn't "read" the code inside the .rs file, writting on this file using eclipse is the same as writting on any single text editor.

I know the sample above needs a Kernel, but how can I write it, if Eclipse doesn't read its code format? I know the simple `typedef struct` constructor in C, but I'm not familiarized with kernel declarations and arguments in C99

I can only find errors using `project > clean`, it seems to "refresh" the compiler, but anyway, I don't have any identation help, text-coloring, anything, only a file with black texts on it, what can I do to fix this? I also tried to open the .rs file with **Dev C++** and **Notepad++**, but I had the same result. Maybe my machine doesn't know the C99 code formating?

Is there anything I can do?

Thanks in advance.

*I'm using Eclipse Luna with ADT pluging, SDK build tools currently on 23.0.2 and everything is updated to the latest version.*

Comment: A simple workaround: From the Renderscript "*.rs" file, insert a line `#include <YourRenderscriptSource.h>`, and then put all of your Renderscript code there (or those lines of code for which highlighting is important to you).

Comment: Google is moving toward Android Studio. Android ADT is a Google-provided plugin; therefore, it is not the Eclipse responsibility to resolve this. Do not expect too much Google enhancements on the Eclipse Android ADT.

Comment: Thx @rwong, I do appreciate your help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C99 specification RenderScript uses for its kernel code is simply C, so you can use any editor capable of editing C/C++ files such as those two you mentioned. This should help you get syntax highlighting at least. You'll just need to configure them to treat .rs files as C code. See for example [this page](http://allthingsmarked.com/2009/07/29/associate-file-extensions-with-specific-languages-in-notepad-plus-plus/) that explains how to do that in Notepad++.

If you really want to keep everything within Eclipse though, you could also try installing the C development environment for Eclipse, but that might be overkill just to get syntax highlighting there. I doubt you would get any actual context/function help or better error reporting with that, since the RS API is still not well integrated into any IDE anyway.

Comment: Thank you, it'll really help me, but do you know if is this "normal" with eclipse? Anyway, +1

Comment: From what I know, this is just how it is with Eclipse for now. I'm sure (I hope) they will eventually integrate the RS API better into ADT to provide better error feedback and such (and maybe even RenderScript debugging), but for now that's how it goes. I work with RS a lot, and I also have to constantly clean the project as you mentioned, and so on.

Comment: thank you for your help. You said you work with RS, do you know anything about the following issue? I posted the question here, please, take a look and tell me what you think. I can learn everything  by my self, I just want to solve the missing class problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560313/missing-mesh-class-on-renderscript-support-library